# WCF service receives incorrect parameter data

Tags: c#, wcf, parameter-passing, missing-data

There is a service which is migrated to WCF. The most methods have int, string, DateTime parameters and everything is working fine, but one method receives an array of custom class objects.

```
[DataContract]
public class Term
{
    [DataMember]
    public DateTime Date;
    [DataMember]
    public decimal Amount;
}
```

//

```
public int UpdateTerm(int id, int documentId, Term[] terms)
{
  // it receives the passed Term array with all objects 
  // but here all the Dates are 01.01.0001 and all Amounts are 0.00
}
```

I have added all the `ServiceContract`, `OperationContract` attributes in the Interface.
Why are Dates 01.01.0001 and Amounts 0.00, like the array members were constructed again?
Other services are working OK, there isn't anything specific..

Simplified client code:

```
Term[] terms = new Term[3];
for (int i = 0; i < rows.Length; ++i)
{
  terms[i] = new Term();
  terms[i].Amount = 10;
  terms[i].Date = DateTime.Now;
}

MyService service = new MyService();
try
{
  id = service.UpdateTerm(1, 2, terms);
  service.Close();
}
catch
{
  service.Abort();
  throw;
}
```

Comment: is terms marked as a [DataContract], the properties of that class need to be marked as [DataMember]

Comment: @TMcKeown yes they are marked as You can see :)

Comment: did you possibly add these attributes after the client originally got the stub classes?  Have you updated the service reference from the client to ensure you have a current version of this datacontract class?

Comment: I guess you would had in order to set them on client...  hmm..

Comment: The service and that class with attributes were created before few months. By this time service has been published un service references updated about 50 times..
Sorry, I didn't understand Your last comment. For example I create an array of 3 elements and dates are 03.04.2013. I can see that in debug before calling service.UpdateTerm(...). And in service debug I see those 3 elements with dates 01.01.0001.

Comment: can you share your client code?

Comment: @TMcKeown just added simplified client code

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43935/discussion-between-t-mckeown-and-user646263)

Comment: Why your loop is limited by some `rows.Length`? Here: `for (int i = 0; i < rows.Length; ++i)` what is rows.Length?

Comment: @Tony actually my array should be populated from `DataRow[] rows` which is the same length. I think it is not important, so I simplified the code.

Answer (score 1):

We just ran across a similar issue. Try updating the ***Specified property and see if that works. It did for us:

```
Term[] terms = new Term[3];
for (int i = 0; i < rows.Length; ++i)
{
  terms[i] = new Term();
  terms[i].Amount = 10;
  terms[i].Date = DateTime.Now;
  terms[i].AmountSpecified = true;
  terms[i].DateSpecified = true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @mattkab, I will try this later. As these `Term`s were formatted to CSV string in the service, I have found a workaround by passing a string already from the application.